# How to merge array inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How to merge array inside foreach loop in php ?

Here is my Code:

```
$subjects = $this->db->order_by('id','desc')->get_where('tbl_class_management', array('status'=>'1','teacher_id'=>$this->teacher->id))->result();
foreach ($subjects as $key => $s) {
   $std = $this->db->get_where('tbl_student', array('batch'=>$s->batch,'semester'=>$s->semester,'faculty'=>$s->faculty))->result();
debug($std);
}
```

Comment: which array do you want to merge?

Comment: do u want to store all data in $std array?

Comment: where are the arrays to merger =????

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR: Yes, I want to store all data in $std array. and i want it outside foreach loop .

Comment: @MuhammadUsman  : I want to merge $std array .

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR : okay , let me check . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to store all your data in `$std` array by iterating over `$subjects` array, declare your $std array outside the loop then sipmly push data in this one by one when you iterating over loop, use like this

```
$subjects = $this->db->order_by('id','desc')->get_where('tbl_class_management', array('status'=>'1','teacher_id'=>$this->teacher->id))->result();
$std=[];
foreach ($subjects as $key => $s) {
    $std[] = $this->db->get_where('tbl_student', array('batch'=>$s->batch,'semester'=>$s->semester,'faculty'=>$s->faculty))->result();
}
$std = json_decode(json_encode($std,true),true);
print_r($std);
```

Answer (score 0):

The general formula for merging two arrays is as follows (merging $array_m into $array_o):

```
foreach($array_m as $key=>$value){ 
    $array_o[$key] = $value;
}
```

$array_o would now contain all of the elements of $array_m

EDIT: I just noticed in your post that you seem to want to use the array_merge function. You could also do the following:

```
$array_o = array_merge($array_o, array_m);
```